# Best way to get the column filtered from a list in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Just would like to different approached to get a list matched/filtered against `df.columns` in a pandas.

Below snippet works perfectly but looking forward for other approaches around.
Even we can consider a function, excuse my brevity as just learning pandas.

```
# list of columns names to be matched & checked
>>> matchObj = ['equity01',  'equity02',  'equity1'  'equity2']

# DataFrame construct
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'equity01': [1, 2, 3], 'equity02': [4, 5, 6], 'equity03': [7, 8, 9], 'equity04': [2, 3, 4], 'equity05': [5, 6, 7]})
>>> df
   equity01  equity02  equity03  equity04  equity05
0         1         4         7         2         5
1         2         5         8         3         6
2         3         6         9         4         7

# One way to  with list comprehension as follows..
>>> print(df[[col for col in matchObj if col in df.columns]])
   equity01  equity02
0         1         4
1         2         5
2         3         6
```

Thank a mile in advanced for any suggestion and solutions around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using  [`pd.Index.intersection()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
df[df.columns.intersection(matchObj)]
```

---

```
   equity01  equity02
0         1         4
1         2         5
2         3         6
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`pd.Index.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html)

```
df.loc[:,df.columns.isin(matchObj)]
   equity01  equity02
0         1         4
1         2         5
2         3         6
```

Comment: This is another excellent piece  of getting job done +1, this was i was trying with `df.columns.isin` but could not get it .

Comment: i like this too.. :)